Kong API gateway not accessing postgres
I had a pretty functional kong installation but now it stopped working and I can't guess the reason. It was installed using a docker-compose file, that assembled 4 containers: kong, postgres, migrations and konga. Now when I try to up the file, kong's logs says something like:
Cannot mkdir /tmp/resty_fozOysRNjN: Permission denied
Just for a test, I tried to run the container as root and it complains in another way:
2024/06/17 16:10:49 [error] 1#0: init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:660: [PostgreSQL error] failed to retrieve PostgreSQL server_version_num: connection refused
Just for the record, postgres is up and running (I can reach to it with psql) and I tried the same docker-compose file in another machine and it works smoothly. So, running out of clues, I ask if you guys have any idea I could give a try.
Thanks
docker-compose:
services:
  kong-db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: kong
      POSTGRES_DB: kong
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kong
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - kong-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - kong-net

  kong-migrations:
    image: kong:latest
    command: /bin/sh -c "sleep 10 && kong migrations bootstrap --vv"
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
      KONG_PG_HOST: kong-db
      KONG_PG_PORT: 5432
      KONG_PG_USER: kong
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD: kong
      KONG_LOG_LEVEL: debug
    depends_on:
      - kong-db
    networks:
      - kong-net

  kong:
    image: kong:latest
    command: /bin/sh -c "sleep 30 && kong start --vv"
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
      KONG_PG_HOST: kong-db
      KONG_PG_PORT: 5432
      KONG_PG_USER: kong
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD: kong
      KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
      KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
      KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
      KONG_LOG_LEVEL: debug
    depends_on:
      - kong-migrations
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "8001:8001"
      - "8444:8444"
    networks:
      - kong-net

  konga:
    image: pantsel/konga
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    depends_on:
      - kong
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "sleep 40 && npm start"
    networks:
      - kong-net

volumes:
  kong-db-data:

networks:
  kong-net:
    driver: bridge


https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/4363

Thank you by the pointer, Daniel. Unfortunately the solution for these guys in this old thread was just to add a KONG_PG_PASSWORD environment variable, which is not my case. Besides, as I said, the same set of configurations works with psql on the same  machine (and the docker-compose runs smoothly on another machine). I'm afraid I have to dig deeper.
